# Cannot boot Windows 10 installer on HP EliteBook 8560w

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-installation, windows-installer, installer

I have a HP EliteBook 8560w on which I want to install Windows 10.
I tried to create an installer USB disk on a SD card and an external HDD.
For this I used two methods:

1. Media Creation Tool
2. Rufus with a Windows 10 image (business editions downloaded from MSDN subscription). I selected "MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI-CSM"
   [image]

With the first method I just get a black screen and the laptop continuously restarts but never passes the boot step.
With the second method I just get the error

> A disk read error occurred
>
> Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart

I also tried to enable UEFI in BIOS but I get the same error.

The BIOS is updated to the latest version F.63 Rev.A / Oct 27, 2016.

Any idea of what could be the issue?

Comment: USB boot problems on a [similar model](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Boot-and-Lockup/elitebook-8460p-will-not-boot-from-USB/td-p/5853142)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the SD card. I've put the installer on a USB drive and it worked.

Comment: As far as I remember I tried in the past to put the Ubuntu installer on a SD card and it worked.